# How to resolve Xcode duplicate bundle ID issue

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase, bundle

I have a registered bundle ID that has been written in camelcase like `com.Company.App` and in Firebase the id was entered all lowercase. This was fine until I added push notification certificates and it complained that the bundle ID in the `P12` file didn't match. I had to remove the Firebase app and create a new one with the matching bundle ID.

Now, Xcode wont install my app and throws the error: `This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains.` - complete nonsense.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I think this was an issue with Flutters internal bundle ID for the framework

Comment: I think you had run flutterfire configure again after ID changes

Comment: I had an issue like this and I resolved it by updating the bundle ID of the iOS app from XCode. It could also be that the GoogleService-info plist file in iOS hasn't been updated after you created a new app on Firebase?

Comment: See below. Was a Flutter bundle ID I changed too. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

this happened because I edited the Flutter framework info file and changed the bundle ID there too. It should stay as `flutter.io.app`. So was unrelated to the case.